# Number of open sockets in my server over certain port

Tags: c#, sockets, performancecounter

I'm working on a C# project that shows server data and status. I would like, among other things, to show the following data:

1) The number of open sockets in the server (easy) over a certain port (hard).

2) The usage of CPU and RAM.

Regarding number 1, I need help from you with the specific port part....

Regarding number 2, I'm using PerformanceCounter which works locally but in the server I get "System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the registry key 'Global' is denied". How can I overcome this?

Thank in advance

EDIT: Code snippet of what I've tried to do in number 1:

```
// 1. How many users are connected (checking how many open sockets to port 5000)
                int count = 0;
                IPGlobalProperties ipGlobalProperties = IPGlobalProperties.GetIPGlobalProperties();
                TcpConnectionInformation[] tcpConnInfoArray = ipGlobalProperties.GetActiveTcpConnections();

                foreach (TcpConnectionInformation tcpi in tcpConnInfoArray)
                {
                    if (tcpi.LocalEndPoint.Port == 5000)
                    {
                        count++;
                    }
                }
```

ANOTHER EDIT: I've solved number 2 with the help of this great topic: [Registry access error when Migrating ASP.NET application to IIS7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2142730/registry-access-error-when-migrating-asp-net-application-to-iis7)

Comment: Sockets cannot share a port, so the number of open sockets over a certain port will either be zero or one.

Comment: Clients can't connect to my server in port "5000" (for instance) at the same time?

Comment: That's complicated. A single socket is listening to port 5000 (try to bind a second one to that port and you will receive `EADDRINUSE`). When a connection on port 5000 is accepted by the program, the system will create another socket that the program can use to access the data. But there is only one listening socket.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: yes, but the accepted socket still has a local port of 5000 in that example. It seems reasonable to assume that's the port the OP is talking about, and the number of open sockets on that port will be `# of clients plus 1` (the `plus 1` to account for the listening socket).

Comment: I don't understand the question. Are you trying to obtain this information by writing a whole separate program from your server? Or are you trying to implement code within the server process itself to do this? You should show [a concise, complete code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that unambiguously illustrates the context of what you are trying to accomplish, as well as what you've tried so far.

Comment: @PeterDuniho What you described to Frederic was what i'm looking for. I want to have the number of open sockets (accepted sockets, as you called it) that has port 5000. Is there any way that can be achieved?

Comment: My other questions to you still stand.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I've develop a web application, that lies in my server, that tries to obtain this information. About code snippet, I can only show what I have tried, See edited question

Comment: The code you tried looks reasonable. Did it do what you want? If not, what did it do? As far as question #2, sounds like a simple account rights issue; you need to run the server under an account with permission to get those counters.

Comment: @PeterDuniho The result of the code above is always 0, which doesn't make sence as I, as a client that accessing the web app, am one of the clients online. Is there something wrong with it?

Comment: BTW, It's important to me to point out that number 2 was finally solved with the help of the following topic - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2142730/registry-access-error-when-migrating-asp-net-application-to-iis7

Comment: Your code is fine. When I run that code on my own PC, I get exactly the same list as I get if I type `netstat -a -p tcp -n` on the command line. So your first step in debugging will be to run that `netstat` command to see what you should expect, then to debug the code and see if and how it's different from what `netstat` returned. Of course, you could always do it explicitly, by just adding code to the server to track all of the connections it makes and maintains; but the code you have should work, so you just need to debug it to figure out why it doesn't.

Comment: Yeah I just figured out that it's fine. Thank you